# add whitespace to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following string

```
NSString *word1=@"hitoitatme";
```

as you can see, if you were to add a space after every second character, it would be a string of words that contain min/max 2 characters.

```
NSString *word2=@"hi to it at me";
```

I want to be able to add a white character space to my string after every 2 characters. How would I go about doing this? So if I have a string such as word1, I can add some code to make it look like word2? I am looking if possible for the most efficient way of doing this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you man by 'White Space'

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: @user1418074 like space between the characters? Example, when you press the spacebar

Comment: I would loop through the letters of the UIIString and then use the NSString methods for inserting/appending to add the whitespaces

Comment: I don't know the definition of "the most efficient way."  It would take me some 20 lines of code.

Comment: @TBlue: see gullivers answer 4 lines :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be different ways to add white space in the string but one way could be using [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
  NSString *originalString = @"hitoitatme";
  NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([a-z])([a-z])" options:0 error:NULL];
  NSString *newString = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:originalString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, originalString.length) withTemplate:@"$0 "];
  NSLog(@"Changed %@", newString);//hi to it at me
```

Comment: however, this will return `"hi to it at me "`, not `"hi to it at me"`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this way:

```
NSString *word1=@"hitoitatme";
NSMutableString *toBespaced=[NSMutableString new];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<word1.length; i+=2) {
    NSString *two=[word1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
    [toBespaced appendFormat:@"%@  ",two ];
}

NSLog(@"%@",toBespaced);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... but after running with multiple tests, it did not quite work on one example. Perhaps I should have made it clear the string will not always be the same so it is my fault. For example, if I use the string NSString *test2= hitobyat yo go", it return an extra space between 'y' and 'o' instead of "yo". Do you have any suggestions? Thank you again?

Comment: @Teddy13: what if your string is "a cd efg hi" what output you expect? and gulliver's answer servers for all purpose I guess

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, not really. What would happen at gulliver's answer if the string was "123455"?

Comment: i ended up using this answer, seems less vulnerable to bugs