# iPhone : insert a character inside a dynamic string

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I have a dynamic string suppose

```
  NSString *originalString = @"Hello my Phone : 123123123 abc 987";
```

In the above string first i have to check were numbers are present inside the string which i got it by doing below code :-

```
 NSString *newString = [[MessageStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                       componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

result i got in newString is 123123123987

But my problem is not getting out numbers from string, i just want to add a special character after every number inside the string which is dynamic.

like i want to make my string like this :-

```
NSString *originalString = @"Hello my Phone : 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 abc 9,8,7";
```

So, please any one can suggest me, what's best possible way to achieve above string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will the text, Hello my Phone : be constant ? Or can that change? Do you only want ',' after digits ?

Comment: complete string will be dynamic ... and i solved this issue and posting my answer also ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeed by doing the following code :-

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9])" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *newString = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:MessageStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, MessageStr.length) withTemplate:@"$0,"];
NSLog(@"Changed %@", newString);
```

Thanks @nsgulliver
by posting answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582782/1305001) :-